# Puzzled on best way to add document management to Django project

Tags: django, reusability, django-apps, document-management

I'm creating a django app which needs some document management functionality - users will upload documents, they'll be viewing lists of the documents and selecting them in fairly simple ways (Primarily, they'll be shown a set of documents in specific categories shared by others in their organisation).

Because I want to integrate this with my app, I don't need a very feature rich user interface (in fact, the app or library could be entirely unusable without further coding without that being a problem). It does have to be usable with django.

**So - what are some good apps or libraries for django that provide appropriate models and UI elements suitable for integration into a larger app.?**

I've looked at the django packages page, and none of the items on there are, as far as I can, see especially suitable. In particular, Mayan does not appear to have been created with integration in mind.

Comment: I know you wanted an existing app, but from your post it sounds like something that can be implemented easily. What do you mean by 'viewing'? Is it acceptable to simply let users download the files? If so, using the Django ORM for categorization and just having the user view the file on their own would be easiest.

Comment: @kz26: I mean that I would like them to be able to view lists, for example. There's nothing very conceptually challenging in document management, but it's the sort of thing that takes time to get right.

Comment: Hey Marcin, I am also trying to solve this issue, what did you end up using?

Comment: @James I ended up rolling my own, using django-taggit for tagging.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't personally used these apps, but Django Packages is always a good starting place. Have you looked at under [Document Management](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/document-management/)?

Mayan ([rtd](http://readthedocs.org/docs/mayan/en/development/), [github](https://github.com/mayan-edms/mayan-edms), [homepage](http://www.mayan-edms.com/)) looks to be actively maintained and pretty mature.

The other two listed are [django-treenav](https://github.com/caktus/django-treenav) and [django-file-picker](https://github.com/caktus/django-file-picker), though they do not seem to be as robust or as actively maintained, but they may be a good fit given your basic needs.

Of course if your needs are simple it may be just as easy to implement it yourself, django model's [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField) is straightforward to use and they have great documentation on how to handle file uploads from forms - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/.

Comment: I did look at Django Packages, and I'm asking because none of these are suitable. In particular, Mayan is a whole project, so I would need to tear it apart.